# How do i set up the server's fully qualified domain name?

Tags: apache, configuration, fqdn

When i try to restart apache issueing /etc/init.d/apache2 restart i get the following messages:

```
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                             apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for server
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for server
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ]
root@server:~# cat /etc/hostname
iSell
root@server:~# hostname
server
root@server:~# hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
root@server:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
108.1.*.*     eins
root@server:~#
```

Note:the two asterisk at the end  of ip in /etc/hosts are added by me at the time of posting.
Note2: let's say my domain name is www.xyz.net

I would like to know exactly what i must do step by step please.
Thank's very much!

Comment: This isn't programming related. Please consider posting on another SE website.

Comment: This behavior is only in ubuntu

Answer (score 22):

Just edit the blank httpd.conf for Apache with the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Add the line:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Save and quit and restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

That will take care of it.

Comment: on Jessie fix /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 2):

Edit you hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

look if you ip 127.0.1.1 as the good name of the server

```
127.0.1.1      srv-web-01
```

and restart your Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Edit the file:
vi /etc/apache2/apache.conf
2) Write in the last line (to see your-machine-name write: cat /etc/hostname):
ServerName your-machine-name
3)service apache2 reload

enjoyit!

Answer (score 2):

1. First, Check your apache version 
   `$ apache2 -v`
2. If your apache version is 2.x, using following command to avoid this message 
   `` $ echo "ServerName\t`cat /etc/hostname`" | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ``

Answer (score 2):

Add the ServerName to  `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` :

```
ServerName [yourservername or localhost]
```

and load the Apache config:
`service apache2 restart`